# find the partial derivative for $e^{xyz^6}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

given $f(x,y,z)=e^{xyz^6}$

calculate $f_{xyz}$

$f_{x}= yz^6e^{xyz^6}$ using the chain rule and multiplying the derivative of the outisde times the inside

then

$f_{xy} = 5yz^6e^{xyz^6} + e^{xyz^6}xz^6*yz^6$

$=5yz^6e^{xyz^6}+xyz^{12}e^{xyz^6}$

$f_{xyz}= [30yz^5e^{xyz^6}+e^{xyz^6}6xyz^5]+[12xyz^{11}e^{xyz^6}+e^{xyz^6}6xyz^5\times xyz^{12}]$

$= 30yz^5e^{xyz^6}+6xyz^5e^{xyz^6}+12xyz^{11}e^{xyz^6}+6x^{2}y^{2}z^{17}e^{xyz^6}$

It wouldn't accept my answer even after making corrections to $f_{xy}$ as suggested and taking that partial derivative I obtained $6xz^5e^{xyz^6}+6xyz^{11}e^{xyz^6}+6x^2yz^{17}e^{xyz^6}$ It said this was still wrong. This question is asinine to begin with and some feed back from those supposed "math lovers" out there would be great.

Comment: $f_{xy} = 5yz^6e^{xyz^6} + e^{xyz^6}xz^6\cdot yz^6$ looks a bit off. Shouldn't it be $z^6e^{xyz^6} + yz^6\cdot xz^6e^{xyz^6}$?

Comment: well using the chain rule on the first we get: $0*e^{xyz^6}+xz^6e^{xyz^6}yz^6$

Comment: which simplifies to $xz^6e^{xyz^6}yz^6$ which is what you got so yes

Comment: simplifying for the next derivative should be: $z^6e^{xyz^6}+xz^{12}e^{xyz^6}$

Comment: $f_{xyz}=6z^5e^{xyz^6}+e^{xyz66}6xyz^5z^6$ on the first part using the chain rule and product rule which simplifies to $6z^5e^{xyz^6}+6xyz^5z^6e^{xyz^6} \to 6z^5e^{xyz^6}+6xyz^{11}e^{xyz^6}$

Comment: using the chain rule and product rule on the second part we get: $12xz^{11}e^{xyz^6}+6x^2yz^{17}e^{xyz^6}$

Comment: giving us $f_{xyz}=$ $6z^5e^{xyz^6}+6xyz^{11}e^{xyz^6}+12xz^{11}e^{xyz^6}+6x^2yz^{17}e^{xyz^6}$

Comment: If you don't put @Arthur in your comment, I won't get a ping (you get a ping now because it's your question). The reason you haven't gotten any more replies is that the site hasn't given me notifications. You've been talking to an emty room and are angry that no one replies. Calm down, please.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's do this:
$$
f(x, y, z) = e^{x, y, z^6}
$$
By the chain rule, with $[xyz^6]_x = yz^6$ we get
$$
f_x(x, y, z) = yz^6e^{xyz^6}
$$
By product rule $yz^6\cdot e^{xyz^6}$ (and chain rule) we get
$$
f_{xy}(x, y, z) = z^6\cdot e^{xyz^6} + yz^6\cdot xz^6e^{xyz^6} = (z^6 + xyz^{12})e^{xyz^6}
$$
and finally, by the product rule (and chain rule) again
$$
f_{xyz}(x, y, z) = (6z^5 + 12xyz^{11})e^{xyz^6} + (z^6 + xyz^{12})\cdot 6xyz^5e^{xyz^6}\\
= 6z^5(x^2y^2z^{12} + 3xyz^6 + 1)e^{xyz^6}
$$